# Releasing a UIView after removeFromSuperview crashes app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management

I have a `UIView` object and I add it as a subview it using `[self.view addSubview:mySubView];`. Afterwards I call 
`[mySubView removeFromSuperview];` and then I try to do `[mySubView release];` but app crashes here.

Does `RemoveFromSuperview` also call `release` on `mySubView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post your code, else its difficult to answer

**Crash code**

```
UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] init]; //manual allocation
[self.view addSubView:subview]; //view retained automatically
[subview release]; //released the manual allocated memory

for(UIView *subview in [scrollView subviews]) {    

    [subview removeFromSuperview]; //released the view retained automatically. Now retain count reach 0/
   [subview release]; // crash.....
}
```

**Code Without Crash**

```
UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] init]; //manual allocation
[self.view addSubView:subview]; //view retained automatically   

[subview removeFromSuperview]; //released the view retained automatically. Now retain count reach 1

[subview release]; // No crash .retain count reach 0
```

You simply do not release things that you have not explicitly allocated or retained yourself.

Comment: I think the "code without crash" could be interpreted as being an endorsement of this as a recommended implementation. But while this won't crash, it's not great. But the best solution is to create the view via something like `[[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease]` and then you don't need any explicit `release` anywhere. Nice robust solution that is hard to make leak. Or, alternatively, create it with `[[UIView alloc] init]` and then, immediately after the `addSubView`, perform the `release`. But by deferring the explicit `release` after the `removeFromSuperview` is a little fragile.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was loading view from nib and not retaining it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `removeFromSuperview` releases the view.

Did you check the documentation? Would have taken about 5 seconds:

> **Discussion**
>   If the receiver’s superview is not `nil`, the superview releases the receiver. If you plan to reuse a view, be sure to `retain` it before calling this method and `release` it again later as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the superview retains all of its subviews so when you remove your view its superview will release it.